# Keep getting jQuery conflicts, can't resolve

Tags: javascript, joomla

I'm currently updating the website http://www.dev.optiekvandevecht.nl/, I updated it from Joomla 3.3.6 to Joomla 3.4.1. Before updating to 3.4.1, a few lightbox thigns wouldn't work. Right now, I've updated Joomla, and the lightboxes work fine, however, now the nivoSlider seems to be broken (and I suppose it's got to do with jQuery errors, `.nivoSlider is not a function`.

I honestly don't see what is wrong, it's a Joomla module called ARI Image Slider, but I can't find anything related to the issues I run into.

Comment: you may try to put your java-script code into footer section...

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible, at least not that I know of, with Joomla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted an (apparently) unused extension and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the jquery is already included in any of the extension. Try disabling jquery in any one extension then check it. I hope it would work.